# The program won't print smallest area and perimeter in the figure

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the smallest area and perimeter but all that comes out of the output the the perimeter and area for the circle class. Here is my main method (the for loops are all the way at the bottom):

```
public static void main (String [] args)//print Figure(Figure[]) 
{
    System.out.println("TESTING FIGURES");
    System.out.println("===============\n\n\n");

    // form an array of figures
    System.out.println("We form an array of 4 figures");
    Figure[] set1 = new Figure[4];
    set1[0] = new Circle(10);
    set1[1] = new Triangle(10, 6, 8);
    try
    {
        set1[2] = new Triangle(5, 12, 7);
    }    
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
       System.out.println("We try to form an illegal triangle");
    }    

    set1[2] = new Parallelogram(10, 20, Math.PI / 3);
    set1[3] = new Square(6);

    System.out.println("The array is ");
    printArray(set1);

    // find the figures with the largest area, largest perimeter,
    // smallest area, smallest perimeter
    Figure smallArea = getSmallestArea(set1);
    Figure bigArea = getLargestArea(set1);
    Figure smallPerimeter = getSmallestPerimeter(set1);
    Figure bigPerimeter = getLargestPerimeter(set1);

    // print these figures
    System.out.print("\nThe figure with a largest perimeter is ");
    printFig(bigPerimeter);
    System.out.print("\nThe figure with a smallest perimeter is ");
    printFig(smallPerimeter);
    System.out.print("\nThe figure with a largest area is ");
    printFig(bigArea);
    System.out.print("\nThe figure with a smallest area is ");
    printFig(smallArea);
}

// print an array of figures
// if the array is null or empty print the message "The array is empty"
// otherwise print 2 lines
// that displays the shape, the fields, the perimeter and the area
// of each item in the array  
public static void printArray(Figure[] figs)
{
    if(figs == null || figs.length == 0)
    {
  System.out.println("The array is empty");
    }
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < figs.length; i++)
        {
            printFig(figs[i]);
        }

}        

// print the shape, the fields, the perimeter and the area
// of fig
// if fig = null, write null
public static void printFig(Figure fig)
{
    if(fig == null)
        System.out.println("null");
    else
    {
        if( fig instanceof Circle)
        { 
                    System.out.print("a circle of ");
            System.out.println( "radius = " + ((Circle)fig).getRadius() ); 
        }

        else if (fig instanceof Triangle)
        {
            System.out.print("a triangle with ");
            System.out.println("sides " + ((Triangle)fig).getSide1() + ", " + ((Triangle)fig).getSide2() + ", " + ((Triangle)fig).getSide3());
        }

          else if (fig instanceof Parallelogram)
        {
            System.out.print("a parallelogram with ");
            System.out.println("sides " + ((Parallelogram)fig).getSide1() + " and " + ((Parallelogram)fig).getSide2() + " and angle of " + 
                    ((Parallelogram)fig).getAngle());
        }

          else if (fig instanceof Square)
        {
            System.out.print("a square with ");
            System.out.println("side= " + ((Square)fig).getSide());
        }


        System.out.println( "The perimeter is " + fig.getPerimeter( ) + " and the area is " + fig.getArea());
    }
}        

// return a reference to a figure with the largest perimeter
// among all figures of arr
// if arr is null or empty return null
public static Figure getLargestPerimeter(Figure[] arr)
{
    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0)
       return null; 
    Figure bigPerimeter = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].getPerimeter() > bigPerimeter.getPerimeter())
            bigPerimeter = arr[i];
    }
    return bigPerimeter;
}        

// return a reference to a figure with the smallest perimeter
// among all figures of arr
// if arr is null or empty return null
public static Figure getSmallestPerimeter(Figure[] arr)
{
    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0)
    return null;
    Figure smallPerimeter = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i > arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].getPerimeter() < smallPerimeter.getPerimeter())              
            smallPerimeter = arr[i];
    }

    return smallPerimeter;
}        

// return a reference to a figure with the largest area
// among all figures of arr
// if arr is null or empty return null
public static Figure getLargestArea(Figure[] arr)
{
    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return null;
    Figure bigArea = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].getArea() > bigArea.getArea())
        bigArea = arr[i];
        }
    return bigArea;
}        

// return a reference to a figure with the smallest area
// among all figures of arr
// if arr is null or empty return null
public static Figure getSmallestArea(Figure[] arr)
{
   if(arr == null || arr.length == 0)
       return null;
   Figure smallArea = arr[0];
   for(int i = 0; i > arr.length; i++)
   {
       if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].getArea() < smallArea.getArea())
       smallArea = arr[i]; 
   }
   return smallArea;
}
```

Also my triangle class won't print the sides and i tried to input an IllegalArgumentException but the side still wont print. Here is the code:

```
public class Triangle implements Figure
{
    // the fields
    private double a, b, c; // the 3 fields

    // the constructor
    // form a triangle with sides s1,s2,s3
    // if s1,s2,s3 do not form a triangle, throw an
    // IllegalArgumentException
    public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3) //throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        s1= a;//hypotenuse 
        s2= b;//base
        s3= c;//height
        if(a + b < c || a + c < b || c + b < a)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
               ("We try to form an illegal triangle");
        } 
    }

    // methods that return the 3 sides
    public double getSide1()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public double getSide2()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public double getSide3()
    {
        return c;
    }

    // @ return the perimeter
    @Override
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    // @return the area
    @Override
    public double getArea()
    {
        return (0.5) * b * c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second expression in a `for` loop means "keep executing the loop AS LONG AS the condition is true" -- not "keep executing UNTIL it's true".  This means that if your loop looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i > arr.length; i++)
```

you will never execute anything in the loop, because `i` starts out as 0 and `0 > arr.length` is `false` and so the loop stops right away.  Change `>` to `<`.

Comment: thank you so much for the help and also explaining and clarifying my error. if you have anything for the triangle class that would also be helpful.

Comment: If you're trying to store the parameter `s1` into the field `a`, perhaps `a=s1` instead of `s1=a`?